# ZXing not reading Brazilian Barcode bills (interleaved 2 of 5) correctly. How can I fix it?

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I am using XZing 2.3.0 for reading ITF barcodes, but ZXing doesn't read correctly Brazilian Bills with 47 digits.

The following sample barcode image ([available here](http://www.shimatai.com.br/images/boleto.png)) is been read as `033915959002000008009557735480001438148929501028` instead of `03399557345480001431548929501020159590000000800`.

A sample PDF (for printing) is [available here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByQMtFUGwDRBWnZObkFBcDR1RVk/edit?usp=sharing). The barcode sequence number is on the top of the bill (a long sequence of numbers separeted by point and space).

I already tried the following code (but with no success):

`Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "AZTEC,CODABAR,CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,EAN_8,EAN_13,ITF,MAXICODE,PDF_417,QR_CODE,RSS_14,RSS_EXPANDED,UPC_A,UPC_E,UPC_EAN_EXTENSION");
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", Intents.Scan.ONE_D_MODE);
intent.putExtra("ALLOWED_LENGTHS", new int[] { 48, 44, 47, 24, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6 });`

How can I make ZXing read that barcode correctly?

Thanks for your help guys, and let me know if I can clarify anything else.

Comment: Are you really sure that the decoded value is wrong? Did you try other barcode readers which give a different result? I tried three other readers which are all give the same result like zxing. So I think the value is correct and the encoded number is little bit different to the human readable numbers on your document. Perhaps there is a technical reason for a difference between the number in the barcode and the other ones.

Comment: @Michael, yes! Because banking apps read this same barcode as "03399557345480001431548929501020159590000000800". But how ZXing reads this in another way? Print the PDF and the numbers in the top of the bill are the numbers in the barcode.

Comment: @shimatai I'm also trying to read 47-digit barcodes from brazilian bills, but zxing doesn't seem to be able to detect anything at all; it does work with smaller barcodes (like 10 digits or less). Did you have to make any changes to the zxing code?

Comment: @Andre, you don't need to declare SCAN_FORMATS, because ZXing reads all formats as default. The point is the order of the fields. The brazillian bills ar showed in a certain order and the barcode is disposed in a completely different order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved! ZXing is reading right. The problem is the brazilian pattern, because the fields are disposed in a different order from the displayed at the top of the bill. That's crazy!

Comment: That's actually pretty common. You should never assume that data read from a bar code matches the human readable text exactly unless you have documentation of the fact that it does.

Comment: @shimatai so... what's the order it's printed?!

Comment: @danguilherme You can find here: http://www.bb.com.br/docs/pub/emp/empl/dwn/Doc5175Bloqueto.pdf

Comment: @shimatai, In fact, zxing reads the data correctly, but Brazilian banks change the positions of values, right? How did you solve this problem? Did you study the Brazilian layout and implement your own logic for it or did you find some third-party package that solved the problem for you? Could you share the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @PedroPaulo send a DM to me on Twitter. It's the same username. We can talk there.

Answer (score 3):

As @Michael says, you aren't actually sure the barcode says what you think it does.

The barcode does say 03391595900000008009557354800014314892950102

http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shimatai.com.br%2Fimages%2Fboleto.png

http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/default.aspx
03391595900000008009557354800014314892950102

http://online-barcode-reader.com/
03391595900000008009557354800014314892950102

Comment: I have 2 banking apps installed in the same device (Motorola D3) and both read this same barcode as "03399557345480001431548929501020159590000000800". But how ZXing reads this in another way? Look that some parts of the ZXing's read are correct, but in a mispelled order.

Comment: Why do you think your app is correct, or, not imposing some transformation ? Every decoder I see gives the same result that the lib does.

Comment: Because those banking apps are approved by Brazilian Governament and are used by thousands of users in all over the country. Those banking apps read that same barcode as "03399557345480001431548929501020159590000000800" and all other apps read as you mentioned. I want to know how can I change the ZXing to make it read as the banking apps does.

Comment: This is still not indicating that the barcode actually says this value. It may be a function of this value from logic in these banking-specific apps. If so the answer is "apply that logic".

Comment: Sean Owen, you're right! ZXing is reading correctly, but the fields of the bill are disposed in a different order.

Answer (score 1):

so, here go some tips about Brazilian barcodes for 'boletos'.

First of all, they use a type of barcode called 'interleaved 2 of 5'. This type usually requires that you set the sizes on the barcode scanner (for instance: to read 44 length barcodes). This is because this type allow 'half-reading' (when you read only part of the code) so fixing a size is a turn around.

The second thing is that what bank expects is a code called IPTE, which is in a different layout than the code in the bars.

To make things worst, IPTE is standardized but the barcodes isn't. So despite of being of the same type and the same lenght, each bank use a different layout. you could have for instance the bank account in the middle or in the end of the code. Only the beginning of the code is standardized and refers to the bank number. From there, each bank developed the rest of the code their way.

You could try to use BoletoNet which incorporates the logics of barcodes into your system or read documentation at Febraban site (Febraban is the Brazilian Banks Association). Both sites and documentations are avaiable only in Portuguese.