# Define String size using Android's Zxing barcode reader

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner, mac-address

I'm trying to set the string's length using a barcode reader. My problem is: I'm trying to create a MAC address barcode reader, encoded as barcode from some computer devices. So, every MAC Address has 12 digits and the barcode must read only 12 digits' strings in order to behave correctly.
My code so far:

```
private void initiateScan(){
        IntentIntegrator integrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this);
        integrator.addExtra("PROMPT_MESSAGE","Put the Mac address at the center");
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ONE_D_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.initiateScan();
}
```

onActivityResult:

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            if(result.getContents() == null) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                String content = result.getContents();
                Log.d(TAG,"scanned:: "+content);
                if(content.length() == UtilConstants.MAC_ADDRESS_SIZE){
                    if(field!=null)
                        field.setText(content);
                }else{
                    // invalid string size, reopen reader
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Invalid code",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    initiateScan();
                }
            }
        } else {
            // This is important, otherwise the result will not be passed to the fragment
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible yet because the general aim for barcode is to **encode** and **decode** but another way you can achieve this is to use a particular barcode format to generate and the same time scan your barcode. Barcodes come with their specific capacity i.e how much content it can store or how much content can be encoded so consider using the **EAN/UPC barcodes** this type of barcodes stores maximum 13.

Answer (score 0):

Representing a MAC address with 12 digits means that the characters used in each digit will be hexadecimal numbers 0-9 and A-F(a-f).

In that case, all of 1D product code, ITF, Codabar, RSS14 cannot be used.
Code128 and RSS14_Expanded are not good uses because the data contents to be used are mainly determined.

If you use it within the support range of Zxing, it will be 1D Industrial Code 39, Code 93, and 2D barcode QR Code, DataMatrix, MaxiCode, Aztec, PDF 417.
[zxing/zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)

There is ALLOWED_LENGTHS in DecodeHintType parameter of Zxing decodeRaw,decode API, so please give it a try.
[Class Code39Reader](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/oned/Code39Reader.html)
[Class Code93Reader](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/oned/Code93Reader.html)
[Class QRCodeReader](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/qrcode/QRCodeReader.html)

[Enum DecodeHintType](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html)
[ALLOWED_LENGTHS](https://zxing.github.io/zxing/apidocs/com/google/zxing/DecodeHintType.html#ALLOWED_LENGTHS)

> public static final DecodeHintType ALLOWED_LENGTHS
> Allowed lengths of encoded data -- reject anything else. Maps to an int[].

There are other options that affect the reading format and notification format, so please try it.

However, there seems to be no function to limit the character code to hexadecimal characters, so even if the number of digits to be read can be specified, it is necessary to check the character code range after that.

Comment: How can i use this "ALLOWED_LENGTHS" ? I tried this and it not worked:        integrator.addExtra("ALLOWED_LENGTHS",new int []{12});

Comment: What is the barcode type you wanted to use and its configuration? For example, by default, you may be notified of barcode type characters, start/stop codes, and check digits. If you do not limit the number of digits, check if you can read it, and try adjusting with that value. Or, depending on the barcode type, Zxing may not support that function. There is such an article. https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/434 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/22234424/9014308